# Error while creating row dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create row dynamically by making some general function so I dont have to write code again and again

Html Code:

```
<a href=# onclick="AddRows('Add')"></a>
<table id="xyz">
    <th>
        <td>ID</td>
    </th>
    <th>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
    </th>
</table>
```

Javascript

Below Java script Codes enter data to table when button is clicked this is demo of the original project so not all original code is copy pasted here. First column is added perfectly but while adding 2nd Column it gives

Error:Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'insertCell' on 'HTMLTableRowElement': The value provided (1) is outside the range [-1, 0].

```
 <script>
     var RowID = 0
        var IndexNo = 0
        var EditIndexNo = 0
        function AddRows(AddType) {
            //AddType = Edit/Add
            var i = 0
            var StoreIndexNo
            if (AddType == "Edit") {
                StoreIndexNo = EditIndexNo
            } else {
                StoreIndexNo = IndexNo
            }

            AddRowToTable("xyz", IndexNo, RowID, i, "", i)
            i++
            AddRowToTable("xyz", IndexNo, RowID, i, "", "Name")

            if (AddType != "Edit") {
                RowID++;
            }

        }


    function AddRowToTable(TableName, TableIndexNo, IDOfRow, ColumnNo,ColumnClassName,Data) {
        console.log(TableIndexNo)
        console.log(ColumnNo)
        var ElementTable = document.getElementById(TableName);
        var IndexOfRow = ElementTable.insertRow(TableIndexNo);
        IndexOfRow.id = IDOfRow
        var CellColumn = IndexOfRow.insertCell(ColumnNo)
        if (ColumnClassName != "") {
        CellColumn.className = ColumnClassName
        }
        CellColumn.innerHTML = Data

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: If you tagged jQuery, why you're using pure Javascript?

Comment: Do you know HTML before even attempting to use Javascript? You table markup is all messed up!

Comment: These two links will help you see where you are going wrong -- (1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell (2) http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/qqtf5huv/ -- Go, figure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are adding 2 columns in one row.
But if you see your code, you are -

1. Adding a row
2. That adds a column at index 0
3. Then you increment the column index to 1
4. Then you again add a row
        Now the problem arises. Now it again adds a row and since the col index has been
               incremented, it tries to add column at index 1.

And thats where it gives error. There is no column 0, so how can a column 1 exists.

So I suggest, you do all this in one function (AddRowToTable) and pass an array that contains information about columns to that function.
That function shall-

1. Add a row
2. Loop through the columns array and add as many columns.